# Return null if no dentist found using filter

Tags: javascript, filter

I have the following code:

```
function findFirstDentist(people) {

let firstDentistFound = people.filter(dentist => person.isDentist) 
}
```

This is been run against:

```
const dentists = [
  { name: "Johnny Karate", isDentist: false },
  { name: "Lucy Hobbs Taylor", isDentist: true },
  { name: "Pierre Fauchard", isDentist: true },
  { name: "Bert Macklin", isDentist: false },
  { name: "Orin Scrivello", isDentist: true },
  { name: "Kip Hackman", isDentist: false }
 ];
```

I am struggling to make this return null if there are no dentists showing true.

Comment: Currently your function: have a filter function with unknown variable `people`; It's not returning anything.; if there's more than one dentist, it would return all of them, not just the first

Answer (score 1):

You could check the `length` of the new array and return either the array or `null`.

```
function findFirstDentist(people) {
    let firstDentistFound = people.filter(dentist => dentist.isDentist);
    return firstDentistFound.length
        ? firstDentistFound
        : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the first dentist in the list (as your function name suggests) use `Array.find()` [MDN - Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
function findFirstDentist(people) {
  return people.find(dentist => dentist.isDentist) || null;
}
```

This will return the first dentist it finds or return null if non are found

**Alternative**

You could use `Array.some()` for this. Read more on this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const dentists = [
  { name: "Johnny Karate", isDentist: false },
  { name: "Lucy Hobbs Taylor", isDentist: true },
  { name: "Pierre Fauchard", isDentist: false },
  { name: "Bert Macklin", isDentist: false },
  { name: "Orin Scrivello", isDentist: false },
  { name: "Kip Hackman", isDentist: false }
];

function findFirstDentist(people) {
  return people.some(dentist => dentist.isDentist);
}

console.log(findFirstDentist(dentists));
```

This will return `true` if at least one person is a dentist, otherwise it will return `false`

Comment: I thought that, but judging by the OPs comment, > "I am struggling to make this return null if there are no dentists showing true." it didnt sound like he wanted the first one .. can easily be done by changing `some` for `find`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and apologies for been unclear. I want to use Array.find, although rather than returning 'undefined' if no dentists are found, I need to return null.